# node.js express server route params: using postman only add the colons before the specific id, it direct to main route "/properties" , if not 404

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, postman

when I use postman to test my backend api, as i was trying to get a specific id, only when I put the colons before the id, the route direct to "/properties".when add the id right after the /, there come out the 404 error. But I already put the colons in the route, which I think is the right way to claim a param as the express doc says. I don't know why the app cant find the right route, and where the problem might be.

[image]

```
propertyRouter.route('/:id')
.get(function (req, res, next) {
    Property.findById(req.params.id)
        .exec(function (err, property) {
        if (err) throw err;
        });
        res.json(property);
    });
})
```

([Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyIrS.jpg))

Comment: Please include code snippets as text within your post rather than as an image. They can be formatted as a block of code using the `{}` button in the post editor or by indenting each line with 4 additional spaces.

Comment: There are too many `});` in your snippet – only 2 functions are called with callback functions, but there are 3 endings trying to match them. The 1st use, before `res.json(property);`, should be removed.

Comment: You may try using tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) to help with finding issues like this. Many editors have plugins for one or both of them to give you feedback frequently.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping.